# Determining if iOS frameworks are actually needed

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks

I am rebuilding an App and at the same time paring it down of unnecessary code and it contains "required frameworks" that I think were left over from copying a previous app shell for building this app. How can I determine if a framework is actually needed. I thought I could just leave them off and build the app and then add them as required to let it build successfully but in the past that has not worked well to my surprise as I have built and tested a previous App without any additional frameworks added and the App built and ran just fine on simulators and actually devices only to find out at submission time I forgot to add the frameworks before submitting it.

I am trying to be proactive and only put in the ones I need. Some, like the MediaPlayer are definitely not needed and I can eliminate them already but some are harder to determine.

Curious if there was an easy way to figure this out.

Comment: Remove the framework under the "Build Phases" tab of your target.

Comment: I understand how to do it but I was wondering about an easy way to determine if they were actually needed the App shell I was using had  8 frameworks and I believe this App needs at this point 3 that I know it needs was curious about an easy way to determine if the others were actually used. I looked in the .h files to see which were included and that may be the proper way but with all the changes in Xcode I may have just missed a new easier way or it may not be the right way at all.

Comment: Delete one. Do a clean build. If you get no linker errors, it isn't needed.

Comment: The fact that it built for you but not at submission suggests that you weren't doing clean builds. If it clean builds without linking the framework, it shouldn't need the framework (unless you were weak-linking before, but then tests should tell you that you're missing features).